# How to update UI once background task is over in ZK?

Tags: java, multithreading, web, zk

I need a solution for a below problem:

- I have a long running task which takes around 20-30 seconds to
  complete.
- This task is perfomed once user click on button on page.
- Once task is over I need to update UI with one more button to
  download the result in a file.
- This should happen in background. So user has not to wait to complete
  the task
- One progress bar can be shown to show the progress.

Other Info

1. Task does some mathmetical computation.
2. I am using ZK framework.

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: I could not find any referece to runOnUiThread in ZK framework . I know its there in Android. can you please share a link about it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton this is not Android..

Comment: Sorry, misread the tags

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the progress bar..zk provides a component..you can see [here](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/miscellaneous/progress_meter) how it works and how implement it.

Now for your task, you can easily use [Event Queues](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Long_Operations/Use_Event_Queues). If you have any problems just ask.

Greets